# Mounting a Sinatra app and all its routes in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sinatra

I have the following Sinatra app:

```
class MyFakeAPI < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "Hello World"
  end

  get "widgets" do
    # code that renders widgets.json
  end
end
```

I am attempting, when running integration tests, to serve this Sinatra app for requests to /api to stand in for a lightly used third party api.

The fake api works great when invoked via web mock's to_rack method.

However when I mount like this:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  mount MyFakeAPI.new => "/api"
end
```

Visiting /api renders hello world, but visiting /api/widgets generates a rails routing error.

How do I route all traffic under /api to the Sinatra app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem ended up being that I missed the leading `/` before widgets in the get route, so it wasn't being routed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue